# Daily download of attachements from mailbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I want to check a mailbox daily and download the attachements of all mails.
For now I just can do this for one email when i set the ItemId manually. My foreach loop is not running. I am getting a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the loop at:

```
FileAttachment attachment = message.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
```

In the XML I can clearly see that the ItemId is correct and there's an attachement as well.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");

service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

service.Url = new Uri("https://fqdn_of_server/EWS/exchange.asmx");

PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.HasAttachments);

ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
view.PropertySet = itempropertyset;

SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);

foreach (EmailMessage message in findResults)
{
    EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(message.Id.ToString()), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
    FileAttachment attachment = message.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
    fileAttachment.Load();
    fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);
}
```

I am using ews v2.0.50727

EDIT___________

This code for one specific email is working fine. But I can't adapt this to a loop. So I guess this is a problem with my query for just the daily mails.

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId("AAMkADM1MWIyYjA4LWViNDEtNGQ2OS1hMDlkLTdiMDY2YTU0Y2MzMwBGAAAAAABO/r/HLJjWR6+SA9a3YgeTBwDUar3a2c6dRJoGCSVHCKVoAAAARWONAADUar3a2c6dRJoGCSVHCKVoAAAAYCsXAAA="), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));

foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Attachement: " + attachment);
        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
        {
            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
            Debug.WriteLine("Attachement: " + attachment);

            // Load the file attachment into memory and print out its file name.
            fileAttachment.Load();
            Console.WriteLine("Attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);

            // Load attachment contents into a file.
            fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);

            // Stream attachment contents into a file.
            FileStream theStream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\Stream_" + fileAttachment.Name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fileAttachment.Load(theStream);
            theStream.Close();
            theStream.Dispose();
        }
        else // Attachment is an item attachment.
        {
            // Load attachment into memory and write out the subject.
            ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;
            itemAttachment.Load();
            Debug.WriteLine("Attachement: " + attachment);
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + itemAttachment.Item.Subject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are assuming every email has an attachment. It might not.

Comment: ... you also assume every email has exactly 1 attachment.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Although this is a special mailbox where every mail supposed to have an attachement you maybe right there's a possibility it is not. I'll change this! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. i thinkt the problem was the `itempropertyset`.

Here is the working code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EWS_API
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange010_SP);

            service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");

            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

            // ignore certificate errors
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

            // set ews uri without autodiscover (just for internal use)
            service.Url = new Uri("https://fqdn_server/EWS/exchange.asmx");

            // filter for only daily mails
            SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

            ItemView itemView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, itemView);

            if (findResults != null && findResults.Items != null && findResults.Items.Count > 0)
                foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
                {
                    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments, ItemSchema.HasAttachments));
                    foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                        {
                            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
                            fileAttachment.Load();
                            fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);
                        }
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                }
            else
                Debug.WriteLine("no items");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a few problems with your code.
You are not iterating through the attachments collection and loading each attachment.
Also you shouldn't be using this code:

```
FileAttachment attachment = message.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
```

This code just gets the first attachment in the attachments collection.

Try changing your `foreach` code to the below:

```
foreach (EmailMessage message in findResults)
{
    EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(message.Id.ToString()), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));

    // Iterate through the attachments collection and load each attachment.
    foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
    {
        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
        {
            // Load the file attachment into memory and print out its file name.
            fileAttachment.Load();
            Console.WriteLine("Attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);

            // Load attachment contents into a file.
            fileAttachment.Load("C:\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);

            // Stream attachment contents into a file.
            FileStream theStream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\Stream_" + fileAttachment.Name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fileAttachment.Load(theStream);
            theStream.Close();
            theStream.Dispose();
        }
        else // Attachment is an item attachment.
        {
            // Load attachment into memory and write out the subject.
            ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;
            itemAttachment.Load();
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + itemAttachment.Item.Subject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is running now, but no files were saved. Further when I'm trying to debug within the second foreach loop there is nothing displayed. It seems like the loop is not triggered

Comment: `if (attachment is FileAttachment)
    {
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;` can be shortened to `if( attachment is FileAttachment fileAttachment ) { // use fileAttachment ` as of recent C# versions.

Comment: @paulvoelker I have updated the code to include the complete `foreach` block. It should work. @Fildor Good spot, thank you. Answer updated

Comment: Do I need to change `findResults`? It seems like there's something missing.

Comment: @MadDev you are using different names (attachment and fileAttachment). I changed the name to attachment but now I get a error `“No overload for method 'Load' takes '1' arguments”`